# close expanded content when click outside element

Tags: html, css, expand

How can i close/minimize the current expanded contents when click outside element(expanded content area)

current code with demo ... :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="background-color:#9300C4;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;border:1px solid black" border="1" width="100%" >
        <tr>
          <td>
             <div ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><h7 style="color:#FFFFFF;cursor: pointer;font-weight:600;"> Collapse >></h2></a></div>
             <div id="demo" class="collapse" style="width:100%;background-color:#FF3B29;" >
             
         <br/>
                <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="white" style="margin-left:2%;"> This is for testing purpose. This is for testing purpose. </Font></a>
              <br/>
                  <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="white" style="margin-left:2%;"> This is for testing purpose. This is for testing purpose. </Font></a>
             
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you .. problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code in your js. [**Source**](http://www.bootply.com/63158)

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

```js
$(document).on('click',function(){
 $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="background-color:#9300C4;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:2;border:1px solid black" border="1" width="100%" >
        <tr>
          <td>
             <div ><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><h7 style="color:#FFFFFF;cursor: pointer;font-weight:600;"> Collapse >></h2></a></div>
             <div id="demo" class="collapse" style="width:100%;background-color:#FF3B29;" >
             
         <br/>
                <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="white" style="margin-left:2%;"> This is for testing purpose. This is for testing purpose. </Font></a>
              <br/>
                  <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" color="white" style="margin-left:2%;"> This is for testing purpose. This is for testing purpose. </Font></a>
             
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $(document).on('click',function(){ $('.collapse').collapse('hide'); })
```

Comment: why don't you accept the answer if it works for you ?